# If $G$ is a group show that if $(a \cdot b)^2 = a^2 \cdot b^2$ then $G$ must be abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> If $G$ is a group show that if $(a \cdot b)^2 = a^2 \cdot b^2$ then $G$ must be abelian.

$\begin{aligned}(a \cdot b)^2 = a^2 \cdot b^2 & \iff (a\cdot b)\cdot(a \cdot b) = (a \cdot a)\cdot (b \cdot b) \\& \iff a \cdot (b \cdot (a \cdot b)) =a(a \cdot (b\cdot b)) \\& \iff (a^{-1} \cdot a) \cdot (b \cdot (a \cdot b)) =(a^{-1}\cdot a)(a \cdot (b\cdot b))\\& \iff (b \cdot (a \cdot b)) =(a \cdot (b\cdot b)) \\& \iff (b \cdot a) \cdot b =(a \cdot b)\cdot b\\& \iff (b \cdot a) \cdot (b \cdot b^{-1}) =(a \cdot b)\cdot (b \cdot b^{-1}) \\& \iff b \cdot a = a \cdot b\end{aligned}$

Thus $G$ must be abelian. Is this right? Is there less clunky way to write it if it's?

Comment: It´s precisely correct.

Comment: Since group multiplication is associative, one can save some steps by suppressing parentheses, but this is the sort of abbreviation you should only make once you've internalized why it's okay.

Comment: If you intended to show explicitly every instance where the associative law is used (probably overkill) then some instances were missed.

Comment: You definitely want to say if $(a\cdot b)^2 = a^2 b^2$ **for every** $a,b \in G$, then $G$ is abelian. Also, once you have internalized the @Travis's comment and are comfortable with dropping all the parenthesis, your proof will become two lines long: $abab = aabb$ implies $a^{-1} abab b^{-1} = a^{-1} aabb b^{-1}$ implies $ba = ab$.

Comment: I, personally think, Snow's answer is the neatest and the best of all given.  But I wouldn't worry about overkill or clunkiness.  The purpose of a student's proof is to demonstrate s/he understands but also to allow the student to convince him/herself. If said student needs to state associativity explicitly to feel that's what it takes to *prove* it, so be it.  In constast I think stating "just cancel the a and the b out from both ends" is a little too breezy for a student who just learned the definitions one lesson ago but is just fine 5 lessons down the road.

Comment: Oh, I missed the OP asking for anti-clunky tips.  IMO I think a good middle clunky minimum/comprehension maximum might be $(ab)^2 = (ab)(ab)$ and $a^2b^2 = (aa)(bb)$ so we are given $(ab)(ab) = (aa)(bb)$ which $ \implies a^{-1}(ab)(ab)b^{-1} = a^{-1}(aa)(bb)b^{-1}\implies (a^{-1}a)(ba)(bb^{-1}) = (a^{-1}a)(ab)(bb^{-1})\implies e(ba)e = e(ab)e \implies ba = ab$ so G is abelian.  Thats perhaps a bit too explicit but it's less "clunky".  I'd personally like to avoid $abab$ and $aabb$ as they are hard to read.

Comment: Thank you very much all! All of this is very helpful to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct, but let's see if we can address "clunkiness".

$$
abab = aabb \qquad \text{Is this right or not?}
$$
Multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ on the left, we get
$$
bab = abb \qquad \text{Is this right or not?}
$$
Multiplying both sides by $b^{-1}$ on the right, we get
$$
ba = ab \qquad \text{Is this right or not?}
$$
All this is right if at the appropriate points we invoke **associativity**.  What appears above is really the idea of the proof, and the necessary invocations of associativity are playing an essentially technical role in this argument.  Maybe "clunky" means all the stuff that's necessary for logical rigor camouflages the central idea, which one wishes to exhibit. That's a reason for getting "lemmas" out of the way before getting to the central idea of an argument.

Answer (score 4):

More simply, $(ab)^2=abab=a^2b^2$

Cancel $a$ from the left and $b$ from the right to get $ba=ab$.

Comment: Although correct a novice at group theory should most probably show more steps to help them internalise how the naive view of "cancelling" is actually dependent on inverses.